# switch between fragments without 'FragmentPagerAdapter'

Tags: android-fragments, android

I am trying to switch between fragments on my activity.
I was reading [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/), but my case is a bit different since I don't want/can't use the 'FragmentPagerAdapter', instead, I want that a button that is pressed on activity will switch between 2 fragments.

My activity layout consist of a Button and ViewPager. in Addition I have got Fragment1 and Fragment2.
How can I switch between this fragments using OnClick method?

My Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
     android:text="Switch it"
     android:onClick="switchFragment"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity:

```
public class MainHeaderFragment2 extends ActionBarActivity {    
    ...
    public void switchFragment(View view){
         Fragment fragment
         if(checkSomething())
           fragment = new Fragment1();
         else
           fragment = new Fragment2();
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // now need to put the selected fragment in ViewPager somehow. 
        // How? that is my question
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate your `ViewPager` then? Are you using `ViewPager` just so that you can replace fragments? If so, you shouldn't use that and should instead use FragmentManager instead.

Comment: @kha can you be more specific? I saw that if I want to use FragmentManager I need to replace by the line: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment); But what should be the view representation of the fragment_container in my layout.xml?

Comment: Too long to answer in a comment. Posted as answer instead. The answer may not be correct based on your question and the presence of ViewPager in your layout. If so, let me know after you've read it and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, this is what you should do:

Change your layout to this:

```
<Button
 android:text="Switch it"
 android:onClick="switchFragment"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To populate it first time with your first fragment:

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = Fragment1.create();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

To replace it,

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = Fragment2.create();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "optionalTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`Fragmen1` and `Fragment2` are the fragments you want to display or replace.

Comment: The Fragment doesn't have create() method

Comment: Use new fragment() instead if you don't want to use a static create(). It's more of a preference thing.

Comment: how to switch in swipe?